# What is the Java idiomatic way to deduce generic object class based on string/enum or class property?

Tags: java, generics

I'm using an API from an external Maven dependency with the following signature:

```java
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> responseType)
```

the API returns an object of type `T` for a given key from a key value store.

In my application there're several object types which can be returned, for example: `Product`, `Customer` etc.

I'd like to wrap the external API into my service which will receive a key and will return the object found. I can't figure out though how to return the object type from the service. Below is my attempt:

```java
public class MyService {
      public <T> T get(String key, String objType) {
        Class clazz = null;
        if (objType == "Customer") {
            clazz = Customer.class;
        } else if (objType == "Product") {
            clazz = Product.class;
        }

        return externalApi.get(key, clazz); // doesn't compile
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because of `Incompatible types: Object is not convertible to T` error.

How can I properly pass `responseType` to `externalApi.get` and return the correct type without reflection?

Comment: Your idea can't produce type-safe code. You can get it to compile by casting to `(T)`, but you'll have to live with an unchecked cast warning. There's a reason the original API took in a `Class<T>` parameter. It's not your fault, it's a limitation you're facing.

Comment: No: T cannot be determined at compile time

Comment: @ernest_k so what is the best practice here: should `MyService` have a method with this signature: `public <T> T get(String key, String objType, Class<T> responseType)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP may have guessed, this is inherently impossible.

If the call site for `get` could do anything useful to preserve the returned type, `T`, then it would know the type anyway and could supply the correct class (providing this is transitively propagated through call sites).

(Also note, the code uses `==` for `String` instead of  `equals` or `switch`.)

Comment: Great catch on `==`!

Comment: Should my wrapper over the external API be something like this: `public <T> T get(String key, String objType, Class<T> responseType)`?